# Буквы и спецсимволы в строке регулярных выражений

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть подобная строка

```
/$s3..$8Hf
```

Написал регулярное выражение, но что-то оно не работает

```
/^[\$\/\.a-z0-9]{10}$/
```

Прошу подсказать, где ошибка?

Comment: Флаг `i` забыли для игнорирования регистра.

Comment: @azhirov1991 к выше сказанному хочу добавить - метасимволы, которые находятся внутри символьного класса `[...]` __не экранируются__: `'~^[$/.a-z\d]{10}$~i'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя там есть заглавная H, а в регулярке только строчные буквы. Попробуй ...a-zA-Z

Comment: Точно... Уже череп не варит... Упустил нюанс... Спасибо!